# Codename One - Android Material Chip controls in simple layout (or equivalent)

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, codenameone, android-chips

My Codename One app has to feature something like Android Chip controls, or equivalent.

They are used in two places and the layout is:

-for the first place

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup android:id="@+id/chip_group" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip android:text="@string/first_chip_title" android:id="@+id/first_chip" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:closeIconEnabled="false"/>
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip android:text="@string/second_chip_title" android:id="@+id/second_chip" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:closeIconEnabled="false"/>
...
...
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

-for the second place

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/chip_list" 
...
...
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" android:layout_marginRight="0dp" app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"  tools:listitem="@layout/content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

where the content (it's the element of the RecyclerView) is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip android:id="@+id/chip_element" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:closeIconEnabled="false" android:textAllCaps="false" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

(Some layout parameters are included as they are in the code although they are not important here)

here's the effective layout (the example is for the second type of layout, the first one is just a simpler version):
[image: Chips layout image]

What could be the equivalent in Codename One?

Comment: Can you provide a clarifying screenshot? It's hard to visualize the XML.

Comment: @Shai Almog Yes, you can see now.

Answer (score 0):

Flow layout breaks lines pretty seamlessly. It's the default layout for `Container`. I can use labels or buttons to build stuff like that pretty easily. Notice I didn't use UIIDs here which you need to use to add margin/padding so the chips are more distinct from one another:

```
    Container chips = new Container();
    // note you can use Button to make them clickable and UIID to style
    // them any way you want
    chips.add(new Label("a very long label for a chip"));
    
    // I can check the chip manually
    Label checked = new Label("another label");
    checked.setMaterialIcon(FontImage.MATERIAL_CHECK);
    checked.setTextPosition(RIGHT);
    checked.getAllStyles().setBorder(RoundBorder.create()
            .rectangle(true)
            .color(0xaaaaaa));
    chips.add(checked);
    chips.add(new Label("chip label 2"));
    chips.add(new Label("chip label 3"));
    chips.add(new Label("chip label 4"));
    chips.add(new Label("chip label 5"));
    chips.add(new Label("short label"));
    chips.add(new Label("very long label for chip"));
    hi.add(chips);
```

[image]

Comment: Android Chip handles check-uncheck status, but your suggestion is useful as a starting point. I created a "Chip" button class, I need to know how to set blank icon space for unchecked status on the button. How to do it?

Comment: You can set the Gap on `Label` which will impact subclasses or define a theme constant: `labelGap` in millimeters.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with gapValue=getIcon().getWidth(); for the unchecked state but text translates too, in the opposite direction, like recoiling. Then I tried many values and negative ones too. It does not work as you seem to intend. I tried with this.setMaterialIcon(FontImage.MATERIAL_CHECK,0); for the unchecked state and this.setMaterialIcon(FontImage.MATERIAL_CHECK); for the checked state, but they are the same: the icon is ever present. I think the option to disable the icon is missing but should be introduced.

Comment: Are you talking about the gap between the icon and the text? That's determined globally between icon and text (not between the two separate components). The icon width will be 0 in unchecked state so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: If I put 0 the icon is not off, instead it is displayed, while if I put 2 the icon becomes tiny. As you can see the logic is inverted, I need that the icon can disappear when the state is "unchecked". How to do it?

Comment: Put 0 where? In the setGap method? gap theme constant? 
Gap matters only for the space between the icon and text. The spacing between components is padding.

Comment: I put the above mentioned values as width. I need a check/uncheck behaviour, however I see that it is not possible with a single MATERIAL_CHECK icon, I think I have to use MATERIAL_CHECK_BOX and MATERIAL_CHECK_BOX_OUTLINE_BLANK unless you have a solution.

Comment: I think what you want is a toggle button or a CheckBox. It's a drop-in replacement for a button